# Graph intersection using igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

So, I am calculating the intersection of graphs in R using the igraph library. I used the command as:
`str(g1 %s% g2 %s% g3)`.

The graph statistics are as follows:

```
g1
IGRAPH UN-- 68 41 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)

g2
IGRAPH UN-- 149 94 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)

g3
IGRAPH UN-- 164 106 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
```

Now, I calculate the intersection of these three graphs as:

```
temp <- str(g1 %s% g2 %s% g3)
```

When I see `temp`,

```
IGRAPH UN-- 335 0 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
```

How is this possible? When I am calculating the common elements, then how is it possible that the final vertices in the intersected graph is more than the individual elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `keep.all.vertices` argument to `graph.intersection()`, see http://igraph.org/r/doc/graph.intersection.html If you use this argument, you'll need to call `graph.intersection()` directly, instead of using the infix operator, so that you can pass the extra argument. Using the example from the other answer:

```
library(igraph)
g1 <- graph.formula(A -- B -- C -- D)
g2 <- graph.formula(C -- E -- D -- C)
g <- graph.intersection(g1, g2, keep.all.vertices = FALSE)
str(g)
#> IGRAPH UN-- 2 1 -- 
#> + attr: name (v/c)
#> + edges (vertex names):
#> [1] C--D
```

You can pass more than two graphs to `graph.intersection()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example: `g1` has 4 vertices (A, B, C and D) and 3 edges, and `g2` 3 vertices (C, D and E) and 3 edges.

```
require(igraph)
g1 <- graph.formula(A -- B -- C -- D)
g2 <- graph.formula(C -- E -- D -- C)
g <- str(g1 %s% g2)
```

In the intersection (`g`), there are then 5 vertices (A, B, C, D and E), and the only common edge is between C and D.

```
g
# IGRAPH UN-- 5 1 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c)
```

The explanation is that, in order to compute the "intersection" of 2 or more graphs, you need to work on the union of the two (or more) sets of vertices.

I don't any good solution to obtain the "intersected graph on the common vertices". but I can propose something that is maybe quite dirty. Hopefully someone will propose a cleaner solution:

```
ids <- which(V(g)$name %in% intersect(V(g1)$name, V(g2)$name))
g_intersection <- induced.subgraph(g, vids=ids)
# IGRAPH UN-- 2 1 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c)
```

Comment: your solution works perfectly fine. Thanks for the help. However, I still have a doubt. I consulted the igraph library manual, and it is written there that the intersection function finds only the edges that are present in both the graphs. Then, why when we do it directly using only the function `str`, it yields incorrect results. Can you please elaborate on the part where you mentioned `sets of vertices`.

Comment: Also, how do I extend it for three graphs? Should I first run your code on the first two graphs and then do it for the third graph or it can be done directly in one step as well? Thanks!

Comment: The cleaner solution was proposed by @Gabor Csardi himself ;)